# Disocordpy embed columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I saw this fields columns in some embed and I realized that my embeds are boring. My question is - how this columns are made? is it an image or something? how can I add these columns to my embeds? Are these emojis? if so where can I get them? I know I ask too many questions but I am just curious. Thanks[image: columns]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `>` symbol to make those columns.

I've remade the embed shown in the picture:

```
import discord, datetime
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!"); 

@client.command()
async def embed(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = "Deep Stone Crypt Void Run",
        description = "All void subclass run of Deep Stone Crypt for the triumph.\nExperience optional.",
        colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(241,196,15)
        )
    embed.add_field(name="Time", value="Mon Dec 7th, 2020 • 6pm - 9pm PST (UTC-8)", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Links", value="[Add to calender](https://discordapp.com)\n[Convert time zone](https://discordapp.com)", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="\✅ Accepted (4/6)", value="> TMC\n> ArcaneVoid\n> LilRemsy\n> Asal", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="\❌ Declined (2)", value="> Joe_Hammersmash\n> Jeiyiu", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="\❔ Tentative (2)", value="> Awoken Phoenix\n> datigren186", inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text="Created by TMC\nLocal time")
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

client.run("token_here")
```

Output:

[image: embed_output_image]

Check out [`this article`](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/210298617-Markdown-Text-101-Chat-Formatting-Bold-Italic-Underline-) to learn more about Discord markdown.